# Store checkbox values as array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created the following demo to help me describe my question: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-https-6ztj2

I have a form where I submit information and store it in a database. On another page, I retrieve this data, and set the `checked` property for the checkbox accordingly. This part works, in the demo this is represented by the `dataFromAPI` variable.

Now, the problem is that when I'd like to update the checkboxes, I get all sorts of errors and I don't know how to solve this. The ultimate goal is that I modify the form (either uncheck a checked box or vice versa) and send it off to the database - essentially this is an UPDATE operation, but again that's not visible in the demo.

Any suggestions?

Also note that I have simplified the demo, in the real app I'm working on I have multiple form elements and multiple values in the `state`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to work with an array of all the id's or whatever you want it to be your list's keys and "map" on the array like here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.
It also helps you to control each checkbox element as an item.

Answer (score 0):

Neither your add or delete will work as it is.

[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the **length** of the new array, not the new array.

[`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns a new array of the **deleted** items. And it mutates the original which you shouldn't do. We'll use `filter` instead.

Change your state setter to this:

```js
// Since we are using the updater form of setState now, we need to persist the event.
e.persist(); 
setQuestion(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  [e.target.name]: prev.topics.includes(e.target.value)
      // Return false to remove the part of the array we don't want anymore
    ? prev.topics.filter((value) => value != e.target.value)
      // Create a new array instead of mutating state
    : [...prev.topics, e.target.value] 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As regard your example in the codesandbox you can get the expected result using the following snippet

```
//the idea here is if it exists then remove it otherwise add it to the array.
 const handleChange = e => {
    let x = data.topics.includes(e.target.value) ? data.topics.filter(item => item !== e.target.value): [...data.topics, e.target.value]
    setQuestion({topics:x})

  };
```

So you can get the idea and implement it in your actual application.
I noticed the problem with your code was that you changed the nature of question stored in state which makes it difficult to get the attribute topics when next react re-renders  Also you were directly mutating the state. its best to alway use functional array manipulating methods are free from side effects like `map`, `filter` and `reduce` where possible.